# How can I extract just 50 rows from dask Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, dask

I want to extract just 50 rows from Dask Dataframe,but I can't.
Finally I want to make new dataframe which has 50 rows each class.

when I run this code,

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(train_csv, npartitions=30)
classes = train_csv.landmark_id.unique()
for cl in tqdm(classes):
    tmpdf = ddf.loc[ddf["landmark_id"] == cl]
    print(len(tmpdf))
```

the result is

```
1048
359
182
149
94
57
78
157
.
.
.
```

so, each tmpdf must have more than 50 rows.
But when I run this code,

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(train_csv, npartitions=30)
classes = train_csv.landmark_id.unique()
for cl in tqdm(classes):
    tmpdf = ddf.loc[ddf["landmark_id"] == cl]
    tmpdf = tmpdf[:50]
    print(len(tmpdf))
```

the result is

```
1
1
1
1
1
.
.
.
```

I thought index might be wrong.so ran this code,

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(train_csv, npartitions=30)
classes = train_csv.landmark_id.unique()
for cl in tqdm(classes):
    tmpdf = ddf.loc[ddf["landmark_id"] == cl]
    tmpdf = tmpdf.reset_index()
    tmpdf = tmpdf[:50]
    print(len(tmpdf))
```

But the result is

```py
1048
359
182
149
94
57
78
.
.
.
```

What is going in?

And I also tryed `.compute()`
I ran this code

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(train_csv, npartitions=30)
classes = train_csv.landmark_id.unique()
for cl in tqdm(classes):
    tmpdf = ddf.loc[ddf["landmark_id"] == cl]
    tmpdf = tmpdf.compute()
    tmpdf = tmpdf[:50]
    print(len(tmpdf))
```

now I could right result,

```
50
50
50
50
50
.
.
.
```

but the time for execution is too long.
The original reason why I used dask was that's speed...

Answer (score 0):

This line `for cl in tqdm(classes):` gives me the error

```
  0%|          | 0/5 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....py", line ...., in <module>
    for cl in tqdm(classes):
  File "...\tqdm\_tqdm.py", line 1000, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "...\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 2046, in __getitem__
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

so I'm not sure how your code is printing integers inside the loop.

Anyway, if you print out `classes`, you'll see it is a delayed object (`dask` `Series`)

```
print(classes)
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=1
    object
       ...
Name: landmark_id, dtype: object
Dask Name: unique-agg, xx tasks
```

So, IIUC, you need to compute `classes` before looping over it. Use either

```
for cl in tqdm(classes.compute()):
```

or

```
for cl in classes.compute():
```